# Separate links for separate groups

Tags: quick-launch

I'm looking for a solution in the following problem.

In my environment I've got several views for a specific list.
Depending on their usergroup, the users should see different links to different views.
Group1 for example should see link 1,2 and 3... while group2 should see links 4 and 5.

How can I realize this? Can I change the behaviour of the quicklaunch? Or does anybody have another good solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use audiences. This link on [Microsoft.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/target-content-to-specific-audiences-HA010169053.aspx) tells you how.

It definitely works in the Quicklaunch / Left hand nav.

Comment: Thank you Neil. Audiences work great under MOSS 2007. Is there also a way to realize a similar behaviour under SPS3.0 ??

Comment: Audiences are exclusive to MOSS. WSS doesn't include them.